# PHP convert date from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, date

I think this is a simple question.  We have a MySQL database with a `DATE` field, the date is stored in US format (2010-06-01).

In my PHP page where I'll display the date, I simply want to convert this date into a UK format (01-06-2010).

Any help and advice appreciated!

Thanks,

Homer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't specify and your example is ambiguous, but I'll assume you're talking about outputting in day-month-year format. You can use [`strtotime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse a string date into a unix timestamp, and then give that timestamp to  [`date`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) along with the format that you'd like to output your date in:

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date_from_mysql));
```

The manual page for `date` lists all the formatting options that you can give. In this case, `d` represents the day as a zero-padded number, `m` represents the month as a zero-padded number, and `Y` represents the year as a four digit number. Any characters that don't have a specific meaning for `date` come across as-is.

Comment: +1.  It's probably m-d-Y, though, judging from the OP's sample MySQL date.

Comment: @gclaghorn MySQL `DATE` format is 'YYYY-MM-DD' (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html). So if 2010-06-01 is a MySQL `DATE`, it means June 1 2010 (and thus 01-06-2010 is DD-MM-YYYY).

Comment: Perfect - thanks Daniel - apologies if the question was a little ambiguous.

Comment: Simplest & best answer. I hate two lines of code such a simple task. Thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

You can do it right from mysql using [DATE_FORMAT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function.
example : "`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%d-%m-%Y')` as my_formated_date;" will do what you need , just make sure to use in fetch method my_formated_date column

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the date with this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

It will return an integer which is number of seconds since 1970 (called a Unix timestamp).

Then use this function to format that number any way you like:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Date object in PHP using the DateTime::createFromFormat feature.

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $sql_date);
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
?>
```

Comment: Quick edit. Thought I had a stray apostrophe, turns out I was missing the other.